# EntityFrameWork Core Many-To-Many Relationship Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I dont know alot of English Lang But I will try...

so i have this error

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Conversation_User_Users_UserID' on table 'Conversation_User' may cause 
cycles or multiple cascade paths.
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

and my code is:

AppDB:

```
    public class AppDB : DbContext
    {
        public AppDB() : base() { }
        public AppDB(DbContextOptions<AppDB> options) : base(options) { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TetraMessangerDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation_User>().HasKey(cu => new { cu.ConversationID, cu.UserID });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message_Media>().HasKey(mm => new { mm.MediaID, mm.MessageID });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Participant>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserID, p.GroupID });
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Conversation_User> Conversation_User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Conversation> Conversation { get; set; }
    }
```

User:

```
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Participants = new List<Participant>();
            SenMessages = new List<Message>();
            ResMessages = new List<Message>();
        }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public string EMail { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool Activate { get; set; }
        public int MediaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Media Media { get; set; }

        public virtual UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("SenderUser")]
        public virtual List<Message> SenMessages { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("ReciverUser")]
        public virtual List<Message> ResMessages { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Conversation_User> Conversation_User { get; set; }
    }
```

Conversation:

```
    public class Conversation
    {
        public Conversation()
        {
            Conversation_User = new List<Conversation_User>();
        }
        public int ConversationID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public int MediaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Media Media { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Conversation_User> Conversation_User { get; set; }
    }
```

Conversation_User:

```
public class Conversation_User
{
    public int ConversationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

so I see alot of same quastion but i dont understand ...

i dont have multiple path so why i get this error.

can some body explain this.

**Note**: I have alot of entitys with the same problem in Many-To-Many Relationship but if i can solve this, I will understand how to solve thim.

and thanks for helping me.

**Edit**: I tried this but still getting the same

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation_User>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
        .WithMany(p => p.Conversation_User)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserID)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation_User>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Conversation)
        .WithMany(p => p.Conversation_User)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ConversationID)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```